# Display characters in 20x4 LCD screen using 8-bit mode

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, lcd

I want to make a python program to display characters in a 20x4 LCD screen. My LCD is Topway LMB204A. Here is the [datasheet](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/LMB204A-datasheet.html).

I tried use a program in this site http://www.raspians.com/16x2-and-20x4-lcd-screens/ but it didn't display anything.

I want to use GPIO, could anyone help me?

Comment: can you a snippet of code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: is your GPIO working? Have you tested voltages on it? Have you checked with an oscilloscope? Have you tried to light a LED? Are you using the right ports? (this is not trivial, I have an old raspberry and the port ordering had changed, or something alike)

Comment: Have you checked the contrast on the LCD (they often have a pot built in or you should connect one externally)? Also what version and revision of the Pi do you have?